# How to deal with invalid unicode BeautifulSoup without converting to utf-8?

Tags: python, html, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to parse a website's HTML with python and there is one troublesome character u011f that gives the following error:

```
Function call:   soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
                 print (soup)

Error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u011f'
```

If I do this instead and encode to utf-8,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").encode('utf-8')
```

It removes the error, but I cannot do that because I am calling the find function later, and it must be in unicode. If I call the find function after encoding to utf-8, I receive the following error:

```
Function call:   worksTable = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'id': 'some_id'})
Error: TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

I have spent hours already on this code and could not find any answers here that fit my case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup4 stripped\_strings gives me byte objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694858/beautifulsoup4-stripped-strings-gives-me-byte-objects)

Answer (score 0):

When you encode the soup, it becomes a `string`.

The following line of code

```
BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").encode('utf-8')
```

will return a string object and so will not support a `find(tagname, attrs={})` method call which should be used on a `BeautifulSoup` object.

I think you should encode the response text before making the soup to get a better result.

```
responseTxt = response.text.encode('UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(responseTxt, 'html.parser')
idv = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'id': 'some_id'})
print(idv.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my response currently does not have an encode function.  I am using the Requests module. Here is my code:

    session = requests.Session()
    params = {}
    response = session.post('some_url', data=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)

Comment: Ok, so i tried using response.text.encode('UTF-8), but it does not change anything and produces the same response as response.content.
The invalid character gets converted to '&#287;' and the top http info is  content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" if that helps. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Shruf did you try the answer given on the possible duplicate?

Comment: Yes, the html5lib solution converts the character to a strange question mark with unicode ufffd, which still gives the same error. 
The lxml solution doesn't seem to affect anything, I still get the same error parsing with lxml as opposed to html.parser.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that it was problem with my desktop codec. The same code runs fine on my laptop. I'm very confused about this, but will find a way to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `encode()` on `find()` instead of soup, here is an example:

```
worksTable = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'id': 'some_id'}).text.encode('utf-8')
```